# Change display resolution only when specific process is launched

Tags: windows-11

Is it possible to have some script or something attached to chosen by me process that would change display resolution when it's turned on and then go back to original resolution when that process is closed?
Im on Windows 11 if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Reso might work for you: https://www.bcheck.net/apps/#reso

It creates shortcuts to launch programs at a certain screen resolution. When you close the program, the screen resolution changes back to what it was.

Comment: Thank you for this, I've problem with it, as soon as i launch program from created shortcut display resolution goes to selected one, however tho it goes back to previous shortly after.

Comment: That means whatever program or game you are launching is also setting the resolution. The only way to get it right, is by changing the resolution in that program/game. Note that some games don't specify resolutions in their settings, but they have a config file you can edit and change the resolution there. Older game are usually the way to use modern resolutions with. Sometimes you need a patch for a game and sometimes its just not possible.

Comment: Nope. I found that this game (Tibia, which is quite old) shortcut is indeed launching the one i specified but shortly after it's launching other executable file. When I tried to link reso to that executable it indeed worked however it can't be done that way as the game is also launching battleye so it only works when I start the game from that executable on which reso doesn't work.
There's no config file in which I can change resolution, it always goes for display resolution. Which is why in my case I'd need something that changes resolution when specific process is launched.

Comment: Programs become processes when loaded into memory. So, it does exactly what you're saying it needs to do.. I think tibia will only work at one resolution, for whatever reason, and there are many old games like that. Perhaps reso won't work, but it's because of the game.